# Simplify trigonometric expression of hyperbolic functions

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

I have $\cos^2x\cosh^2y - \sin^2x\sinh^2y$. I saw it written simplified as $\cosh^2 y - \sin^2 x$. But I don't get how to get it.

My attempts were to write $\cosh^2y -1$ instead of $\sinh^2y$ but that way I get $\cos^2x\cosh^2y - \sin^2x\sinh^2y = \cosh^2y(\cos^2x-\sin^2x) + \sin^2x$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should it be $$\cos^2x\cosh^2y+\sin^2x\sinh^2y=(1-\sin^2x)\cosh^2y+\sin^2x(\cosh^2y-1)$$

Comment: then I have $\cos^2x\cosh^2y+\sin^2x\sinh^2y=(1-\sin^2x)\cosh^2y-\sin^2x(\cosh^2y-1) = \cosh^2y - \sin^2x\cosh^2 - \sin^2x\cosh^y + \sin^2x =  \cosh^2y - 2\sin^2x\cosh^2 + \sin^2x$. Which is not equal to $\cosh^2y-\sin^2x$

Comment: seems like there should be + instead of -. In that case I'm getting the right answer.

Comment: I was actually finding real, imaginary parts of $\tan(x+yi)$ and the modulus of it.
I have $$Re(\tan(x+yi)) = {\frac{\sin2x}{\cos2x+\cosh2x}}, Im(\tan(x+yi))=  {\frac{\sinh2y}{\cos2x+\cosh2x}}$$.
But I can't seem to find the modulus.
The answer is $${\sqrt{\frac{\cosh2y-\cos2x}{\cosh2y+\cosh2x}}}$$

Comment: Bottom of fraction should be $\cosh2y+\cos2x$